# Proving $[G:P] \equiv [N_G(P):P] \pmod{p}$

Tags: abstract-algebra

$[G:P] \equiv [N_G(P):P] \pmod{p}$ where $P$ is p-subgroup.

Let $X=\{ \text{the cosets of P} \}$. Suppose $P$ acts on $X$. Then, we have $$|X| \cong |X^P| \pmod{p}$$
where $X^P = \{x \in X | p \cdot x = x \text{, for all $p \in P$} \}$.

If $x \in X^P$, we have $x=gP$ such that $g \in N_G(P)$.

I have problem seeing clearly why $|X^P|=[N_G(P):P]$.

I can vaguely grasp that there is overcounting by $P$ but I would like to see this rigorously.

Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: How does $P$ act on $X$?

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mention the action. $p \cdot gP = pgP$ @Bernard

Comment: Left multiplication. I thought so but wanted to be sure.